# How to set a custom drawable directory for unit testing in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

In Android Studio I put some drawables that my test need to run in the res folder of the androidTest folder like this:

app/src/androidTest/res/drawable/image.png

I can see the new added drawables marked as **drawable/image.png (androidTest)** inside Android Studio. But when I try to access the drawable using R.drawable.image can't be found.

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Is like the R.drawable of the test its not generated.

How can I access this drawable or do to be generated in R.drawable?

Comment: SOLVED: When I compile again the test.R.drawable was generated and I can access correctly. I think something it's not refreshed the first time I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: When I compile again the test.R.drawable was generated and I can access correctly. I think something it's not refreshed the first time I did. Now is working OK.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but "test.R.drawable..." did not work either; I ended up moving the test image to main/res/drawable, which is not ideal, but it worked. Also, I had to restart AndroidStudio to get the build to recognize the file. I feel like I must just be missing something dumb, but it works.